# Higher order derivatives test for critical and hypercritical points

Tags: calculus, derivatives, reference-request, monotone-functions

I found the following flowchart from my friend's notes:

[image]

I have seen multiple MSE posts on how third derivative tests help determine points of inflection but neither have I encountered nor could I find on the internet about how these 4+ order derivative tests work.

Im looking for a reference/explanation as to why this holds true.(I'm particularly interested about the case when the third derivative is zero followed by the 4th derivative test to differentiate minima and maxima)

Comment: See [Wikipedia Higher Order Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test). The idea is to look at the graph of $f(x)=(x-a)^n$ for various values of $n$ (because of Taylor's theorem).

Comment: @peek-a-boo so the thing in flowchart is just for polynomials of the type you mentioned? Do other functions not work?

Comment: It works for all sufficiently differentiable functions. I brought up the polynomial case because the theorem is obvious for the polynomial case, simply by looking at the graph. THe general case is then a "simple" limiting argument. Therefore, if you understood why the test is the way it is for polynomials, then you understand everything. If you want the full proof, then look at Spivak's Calculus, chapter 20, Theorem 2.